# Microsoft cloud Active directory run reports

Tags: powershell, active-directory, office365, cloud

I'm working with cleaning up in our Active driectory after we have moved over to Microsoft cloud in our company. My job is to go through the all the groups in our Store ou on the Active directory server and make sure that the "managed by" is up to date. In this case, all managers of the group are rightly added in the AD on the cloud, but not in our AD server where there is actually none added.

Its a big job, going through 181 groups one by one, adding the apporver/managed by, manually.

I'm trying to figure out if there is some way of getting reports out from the cloud? And if theres a way, or script to update the AD on out server. I know PowerShell scripts to get out information there, but is there a way to also use a script to get the information in?

Thank you for any ideas or help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have to use ADConnect to migrate users a groups to MSOL. So, unless you added new groups to MSOL that don't exist on-prem and you did not set the sync AAD and AADS objects then you'd have groups in one and not in the other.

You can always re-run ADConnect and change those settings, but before doing that, make the changes on-prem first.

To maintain total consistency, your on-prem AAD environment, should mirror you ADDS environment, specifically in hybrid.

Yet, if you are cloud only and did a one way migration, then you have to make those changes in MSOL using the MSOL / AAD cmdlets. The approach however would be the same as if it was on-prem though the cmdlet names are different.

So, practice on an isolated group using the ADAC on your AD server, and open the PowerShell History viewer to copy out the code for tweaking.